# Mod Rewrite and form method GET

Tags: regex, forms, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone explain me how to rewrite get request in a search form?

This is my rewriterule

```
RewriteRule ^Stats-(.*)/?$ history.php?user=$1
```

The form action is

```
history.php
```

But i don know hot to rewrite de url because the form send another "?user=".

Thanks!

Comment: If you can change the action you could make it `Stats-user/` replacing user with the actual username and the rule you have would work the other way would be rewriting the submit into the pretty URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dashboard/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /history\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Stats-%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^Stats-(.*)/?$ history.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi!, thanks by your answer!, i think it is working!, but i have a new trouble now, i have this on my htaccess: RewriteBase /dashboard, with this rule seems like it take me back to root directory, how can i fix that?, thank you very much by your time and apologies about my bad english